# Why can't I play onion.com videos on OS X Safari?

Tags: macos, video, safari

When I try to play videos on onion.com on Safari, I see a black rectangle with no video. I do however hear the sound.

Videos on Chrome play normally.

Comment: Does it require a Flash Player or Silverlight player?

Comment: probably not since i can hear audio… right?

Comment: (also, pretty sure i have the latest version of both installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue too. I turned off my Ad Blocker Plus extension for The Onion's site, and the video played after a pre-roll ad. Give that a try.